# Can't create a UWP app

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, uwp

I recently, upgraded to Windows 10 and got Visual Studio 2015 Community hoping to build UWP apps and ASP.Net 5 apps. At first, I installed everything, but ended up skipping / canceling the Windows 8.1 / 10 mobile emulators (my PC can't even run them). After everything was installed, I went to create a new UWP app (C#), and got this error:

[image: Error]

Next, I try the same thing, but with JavaScript. It works perfectly! on the same UAP 10.0.0.0 that is supposedly missing. The link it provides is completely useless (it sends me to http:/microsoft.com/en-us) -_-.  Oddly, this only happens when I try to use C# or VB.Net, JavaScript UWP apps seem to work fine. What is going on here? Where can I find the real link to the SDK I need?

**UPDATE**

JavaScript UWP apps will be create just fine, but when I attempt to build, I get:

```
Error "10.0.0.0" is not a supported value forTargetPlatformVersion. 
Please change it on the Project Property page.  Test    
C:\Program Files (x86)   \MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.\JavaScript\Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.UAP.targets
```

Comment: I suggest that you avoid UWP apps like the plague. Simple things like File.Create don't work in UWP. The Windows store is a failure because it is restricted to UWP apps. Give it a couple of years and Microsoft will abandon it like the Zune and so many other failed projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the download link for the standalone SDK, maybe reinstalling the sdk will fix the problem.

https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. I have no idea why it was slinking me to the Microsoft home page.

Comment: The win10 tools are required to build JavaScript as well as C#. It sounds like we have a bug - the install dialog should pop up for JS projects as well. I will follow up with my team and file a bug if necessary. The link Rohit gave you is correct - installing that should fix the issue. Note - this link is also available in the notification center, and as a 'bread crumb' in the new project dialog.

Comment: Follow-up: we have a know issue that is preventing the 'Visual Studio Update Required' dialog from showing in a JavaScript project. We hope to fix that shortly. The fact that the link takes you to the wrong place is a separate problem. I will file a bug for us to investigate.

Comment: We've fixed the fwlink so that it sends you to the right place. Thank you for reporting it.

Comment: @Michael Braude: I had the very same problem (js works, c# doesn't, same error message), but installing the sdk linked above did not help. When I try installing the SDK, the installer just tells me "The features on this computer are up to date" and only offers a "close"-Button. Could this be related to the fact that I am running Windows 8.1 instead of Windows 10 on my Dev PC?

Comment: @Michael Braude just like Adrian Grigore mentioned I am also facing the same problem. While features show as being already installed yet it doesn't create the new project or continue using old VS pro(trial version) ones. Any fix?

Comment: ran the setup once again using a web installer-> Modify-> unchecked and checked UWP option and then after it downloaded latest updates its working now

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't always have to reinstall visual studio when something goes wrong because it takes a lot of time to reinstall again. From your question you skipped/cancel that feature, the first thing to do is go to the control panel and double click on visual studio  under programs to Modify the software and enable those features.

In the case, visual studio was working properly before but due to some updates it stopped, go to control panel right click the visual studio  version you have under programs to repair.

If the above doesn't work try to reinstall it again.  I hope this helps.